# Overlapping underbraces in the marginsnote

Tags: math-mode, marginnote, underbrace

I am trying to place a number of overlapping underbraces to the left margin. My goal is to create one similar to the following:
[image: This is overlapping underbraces in marginnote]

This is as far as I could get:

[image: Not so cool overlap]

Basically, my main problem is to place 4 outside the underbrace and adjust the length of the underbrace below. Though still couldn't find how to create to margin notes. The code I used is below. I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\marginparwidth=4cm
\usepackage[left=5cm, right=2cm, top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\reversemarginpar

\marginnote{$\rlap{\ensuremath{\underbrace{\phantom{1+2,\underbrace{1+2}_{3+4}}}_{5}}}\underbrace{1+2}_{3\rlap{\ensuremath{\underbrace{\phantom{1+2,\underbrace{1+2}_{3+4}}}}}}$}[1cm]
By His orders, this decision was announced to the people of Berlin on the next day. 
As long as telephone connections with the bunker remained open, during the succeeding days, many followers and officials begged him to reconsider his

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This addresses your main issue of setting a nested `\underbrace` such that the braces don't interfere with one another. In principle, you can set something in zero-width box (using `\rlap` or `\llap`, or their math equivalents provided by [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) and issue an associated `\phantom` to get the correct horizontal spacing of the missing element set within the `\rlap`/`\llap`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \underbrace{1 + 2}_{\textstyle \rlap{$\underbrace{3 + 4}_{\textstyle 7}$}\phantom{3}}
\]

\end{document}
```